# How can I set width of a table less than 1 percent

Tags: html, html-table, width

How  can I set width of a table less than 1 percent?

```html
<div>
<table class='total_cost table no-margin' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="0.5%" style='background:#4A84CE; float:left; height:20px; padding:0px; border:none; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;'>
 <tr>
   <td class='cost text-right fg-white employee-tooltip' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='padding:0px; border:none;border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background:#F00' ></td>
       </tr>
</table>
<span class="display_time"> 2 hours</span>
</div>
```

Comment: try with:width:0.25%; or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put any width between 0% and 1% like 0.25%, 0.50%, 0.75%

```
  <div>
    <table class='total_cost table no-margin' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="0.50%" style='background:#4A84CE; float:left;  height:20px; padding:0px; border:none; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;'>
     <tr>
       <td class='cost text-right fg-white employee-tooltip' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='padding:0px; border:none;border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background:#F00' ></td>
           </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="display_time"> 2 hours</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: because you said you want less than 1%, i guess 0% is also less than 1%, if you want greater than 0%, you can use anything between 0 and 1 like 0.25%,0.50% or 0.75% according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for help.

Comment: Please hit +1 if you like answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
<table class='total_cost table no-margin' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="0.1%" style='background:#4A84CE; float:left; height:20px; padding:0px; border:none; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;'>
 <tr>
   <td class='cost text-right fg-white employee-tooltip' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style='padding:0px; border:none;border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background:#F00' ></td>
       </tr>
</table>
<span class="display_time"> 2 hours</span>
</div>
```